# Append single line to existing file using Jinja2 template

Tags: ansible

In a (rather long) playbook I have a few entries that append a line to a log file:

```
- name: LOG "Task done"
  lineinfile:
    dest: "{{ full_log_name }}"
    line: "{{ tstamp.stdout }}, {{ inventory_hostname }}, Task done"
    insertafter: EOF
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Thanks to this I can track how many hosts this playbook already has gone through.

However I would like to add a single line when the playbook starts. If I use template:

```
- name: LOG "Start"
  template:
    src: playbook_start.j2
    dest: "{{ full_log_name }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

It creates a new empty file with this line and then my "lineinfile" tasks append its own logs. I would like to keep my old logs in the same file so two runs of my playbook would create log like this:

```
2019-08-19 11:34:56.63446, log.log, *** PLAYBOOK STARTED ***
2019-08-19 11:35:09.12405, Host1, First task done
2019-08-19 11:35:09.12299, Host2, First task done
2019-08-19 11:35:18.94610, Host1, Second task done
2019-08-19 11:35:18.95439, Host2, Second task done
2019-08-19 11:35:19.63446, log.log, *** PLAYBOOK STARTED ***
2019-08-19 11:35:20.33616, Host1, First task done
2019-08-19 11:45:25.84871, Host2, First task done
2019-08-19 11:45:25.83616, Host1, Second task done
2019-08-19 11:45:33.13359, Host2, Second task done
```

I also tried with "lineinfile" but it would create multiple "PLAYBOOK STARTED" lines for each host.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **run_once: true**. Something like below. I have not tested it.

```
- name: LOG "PLAYBOOK STARTED"
  lineinfile:
    dest: "{{ full_log_name }}"
    line: "{{ tstamp.stdout }},log.log, *** PLAYBOOK STARTED***"
    insertbefore: BOF
    run_once: true 
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

`run_once: true` will your `lineinfile` will do the trick.

But nevertheless, I have the feeling that what you to achieve should be done with a callback plugin. You should have a look in `log_plays` plugin and see how you could customize it to fit your need…